# beamer \mode* metropolis theme and standout

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis, mode

When using `\mode*` it seems that this confuses beamer with the `metropolis` theme when using the `standout`-frame option such that after using `standout` all succeeding frames stay in this `standout` mode although not active.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
    \mode*
    \begin{frame}{test}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[standout]{test standout}
    123
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{test no standout}
        
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I would expect that the frame after the `standout`-frame is not typeset in `standout`-mode but, unfortunately, it is. I know that removing `\mode*` solves this issue. But I am using a construction where having it is quite handy and simplifies my document because I do not have to use at every in-between frame text the option `\mode<article>{}`. So, I wonder whether the beaviour is intended or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2024:

You could avoid the problem by using the `moloch` theme, which a more modern fork of the metropolis theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}
    \mode*
    \begin{frame}{test}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[standout]{test standout}
    123
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{test no standout}
        
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

#### Original answer:

This has already been fixed in the development version on github, see https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/335

Until a new version is released to ctan, you can either manually install the dev version or use the following workaroud:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
  \pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
    \ifbool{metropolis@standout}{
      \endgroup
      \boolfalse{metropolis@standout}
    }{}
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \mode*
    \begin{frame}{test}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[standout]{test standout}
    123
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{test no standout}
        
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arne You're welcome!